# Can i send data after each second (reactive) from WKWebView to native in Swift

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift

I am creating a View which displays a local webpage which also has styles and JavaScript using a WKWebView.
I want to send data every second from WebView using node js like this

```
const timerEventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
timerEventEmitter.emit("update");
let currentTime = 0;
// This will trigger the update event each passing second
setInterval(() => {
    currentTime++;
    timerEventEmitter.emit('update', currentTime);
}, 1000);

timerEventEmitter.on('update', (time) => {
    console.log('Message Received from publisher');
    console.log(`${time} seconds passed since the program started`);
});
```

Can i send the log
`{time} seconds passed since the program started`
to native ios app, or send data using react like this

Comment: I see some tutorial just for send data like this: https://medium.com/@mushtaque87/webkit-4bd5cf3dc08 But it's not i want. Does anyone help me with this. Or is it possible?

Comment: If you need your server part send datas to your webview application, you can use sockets.io.

Comment: Is it possible to emit event on js in wwebview and receive in my app (native)

Comment: Yes, socket.io is bi directionnal

Comment: @Alaindeseine can you show me some tutorial for this

Answer (score -1):

You can use socket.io to have server pushing datas to webview application.

Take a look at the get started of socket.io website : https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Tell if you have questions.